# laser_retro not working with gpu_ray

Tags: ros-humble, gazebo-plugin, 2dlaserscan, gpu

The laser_retro in the collision section in an object inside a sim works well with the non-gpu version of the Gazebo `ray` plugin. However, I'm not getting the same results when using the gpu-version of the `ray` plugin.

Does someone know what's going on?

Edit: I put a value in the `laser_retro` of an object in the Gazebo sim but when laser scanner rays collide with that object, I'm not getting any intensity value out of those points using the gpu version of the `ray` plugin. I'm getting intensity values when using the non-gpu version of the `ray` plugin.